# Identifying Column Rank with `dplyr` in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been playing with `dplyr` for this problem, but cannot seem to find a good solution. Basically, I have data on students with their names, year in school, and some numeric statistics. Like this:

```
Name     Yr.     Stat_1     ...
A        Fr.     5
B        Fr.     5
A        So.     5
A        Jr.     5
B        So.     5
C        Sr.     5
```

I know I can use the the command `dplyr::mutate(count = n())` to find the number of rows for an individual student once I've done `group_by()`, but I would like to use the number of rows for each individual in a weighted sum of the numerous statistics (a mixture model if you will). However, there is the case, such as student C, who (whether it be a transfer, etc.) only appears in the data as a Sr so I cannot simply use the understanding that a senior would have been in their fourth year. Thus, I would like to reconfigure the above table to look like the one below, so that I can then use `dplyr`'s `group_by()` and `mutate()` features to weight the various statistics.

```
Name     Yr.    Numb     Stat_1     ...
A        Fr.    1        5
B        Fr.    1        5
A        So.    2        5
A        Jr.    3        5
B        So.    2        5
C        Sr.    1        5
```

Note the `Numb` of `C` is 1 and not 4. I would love any help or direction with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `row_number` after grouping by 'Name'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>%
   mutate(Numb = row_number())
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups: Name [3]
#  Name  Yr.   Stat_1  Numb
#  <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
#1 A     Fr.        5     1
#2 B     Fr.        5     1
#3 A     So.        5     2
#4 A     Jr.        5     3
#5 B     So.        5     2
#6 C     Sr.        5     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(
    class = factor(Yr.,levels = c("Fr.", "So.", "Jr.", "Sr.")) %>% as.numeric(),
    years = n()
  ) %>%
  group_by(Name, Yr.) %>%
  mutate(
    Numb = min(class, years)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

you can get rid of class and years afterwards if they aren't useful.